# I need to observe a Group() of Sprite objetcs for my training agent

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am  trying to test the game "space invaders" by creating and IA agent, so i need to observe the position x and y of my aliens but the aliens are initialized as

```
self.aliens = Group()
```

How can I observe a Group directly? Any ideas ?

I tried to create a list of aliens based on the group

```
 def update_aliens(self, ai_settings: Settings, stats: GameStats):
        """Update position for each alien."""
        self.check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, self.aliens)
        self.aliens.update(stats)
        for i, alien in enumerate(self.aliens, start=1):
            x_position = alien.rect.x
            y_position = alien.rect.y
            self.aliens_list.append((x_position, y_position))

            print(f"Alien {i} - x: {x_position}, y: {y_position}")

        # Collision between ship and aliens.
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self.ship_hit(stats)
        self.check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats)
```

and this is my file kill_step.py where i have the @given for the training :

```
@given("A game with an alien")
def test_impl(test_context):
 

    def get_aliens(aliens_list):
        return [{
            'position': {
                'x': alien.rect.x,
                'y': alien.rect.y,
            }

        } for alien in aliens_list]

    test_context.game = test_context.create(Game, "game",
                                            state=[
                                            State("terminated", methods_to_observe=["end_game", "reset"]),
                                            State("stats", State("score"), methods_to_observe="check_bullet_alien_collision"),
                                            State("aliens_list", func=get_aliens, methods_to_observe="update_aliens")

                                            ])



@when("There is one alien")
def test_impl(test_context):
    test_context.game.reset(test_context.game.ai_settings, test_context.game.stats)
    test_context.game.create_fleet(test_context.game.ai_settings, 1, 1)


@loop
def test_impl(test_context):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            test_context.game.quit_game(test_context.game.stats)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            test_context.game.check_keydown_events(event, test_context.game.ai_settings, test_context.game.stats)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            test_context.game.check_keyup_events(event, test_context.game.ship)

        if not test_context.game.stats.game_active:
            test_context.game.stats.game_active = True
            test_context.game.ai_settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()

    if test_context.game.stats.game_active:
        test_context.game.ship.update(test_context.game.stats)
        test_context.game.update_bullets(test_context.game.ai_settings, test_context.game.stats)
        test_context.game.update_aliens(test_context.game.ai_settings, test_context.game.stats)



@then("The player should have killed one alien")
def test_impl(test_context):
    print("then")

    test_context.assert_equal(test_context.game.stats.score, 50)

@render
def test_impl(test_context):

    test_context.game.render()


@log
def test_impl(test_context):
    return {

       
        "terminated": test_context.game.terminated

    }
```

and this is how i created the space boxes in my file kill.py :

```
@config
def train_impl(train_context):

    train_context.score= 0

    dct = {
        'score': spaces.Box(-1, 1, dtype=np.int64, shape=(1,)),
        
    }

    for i in range(100):
        dct[f'alien_{i}_rect'] = spaces.Box(-1, 1, dtype=np.int64, shape=(2,))


    train_context.observation_space = spaces.Dict(dct)
    train_context.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
    train_context.max_episode_length = 2000
    train_context.total_timesteps = int(5e4)
    train_context.algorithm_type = "MultiInputPolicy"
    train_context.algorithm = stable_baselines3.PPO



@observation
def train_impl(train_context):


    dct = {
        "score": np.array([train_context.game.stats.score]),
    }

    for idx, item in enumerate(train_context.game.aliens_list):
        dct[f'alien_{idx}_rect'] = np.array([item["rect"]['x'], item["rect"]['y']])
    for idx in range(len(train_context.game.aliens_list), 100):
        dct[f'alien_{idx}_rect'] = np.array([0, 0])

    return dct




@reward
def train_impl(train_context):

    close_reward = 0

    if train_context.game.stats.score > train_context.score:
        close_reward += 10

    if train_context.game.terminated:
        close_reward -= 10

    train_context.score = train_context.game.stats.score

    return close_reward

@terminated
def train_impl(train_context):

    term = train_context.game.terminated or  train_context.game.stats.score > 100

    if train_context.game.terminated:
        print("term1")
    if train_context.game.stats.score > 100:
        print("term2")

    return term


@action
def train_impl(train_context, raw_actions):

    direction = ["nothing", "left", "right"]
    train_context.actions = [direction[raw_actions]]
    return train_context.actions
```

And i have this error :

```
  File "C:\Users\amyli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\xumes\training_module\entity_manager.py", line 272, in update_state
    for i in state:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? This isnt fully reproducible.  Having all the code related to your agent and env would be a good start.  Open ai gymnasium actually provides environments for space invaders as well which would simplify this

Comment: I provided more code, hope it's going to be clearer

Comment: You can see in the code you have that you can iterate through `self.aliens`, and each element has a `rect` with coordinates.  Isn't that all you need?

Comment: The problem was somewhere else, thank you for your help !